# INotifyPropertyChanged not working with traditonal binding but works with compiled binding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, uwp

I don't if I am doing something wrong or if there is something I am missing but the INotifyPropertyChanged works when I do it with compile time binding and doesn't work when I do it with traditional binding.

```
public class Students : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string name;
    private string surname;


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if(value != name)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }

        }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return surname; }
        set
        {
            if (value != surname)
            {
                surname = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }

        }
    }

    public Students()
    {
        Name = "John";
        Surname = "Smith";
    }


}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:Students/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <StackPanel Margin="0,200,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}"/>
        <Button Content="Change Name" Click="change_name"/>
        <Button Content="Change Surname" Click="change_surname"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

MianPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Students st;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        st = new Students();
    }

    private void change_name(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        st.Name = "MM";
    }

    private void change_surname(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        st.Surname = "SS";
    }
}
```

I am really confused, because when you bind with compile time binding, it works fine. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any place in which you are setting the current DataContext to your object.

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        st = new Students();
        this.DataContext = st;
    }
```

**OR**: You are setting a datacontext in your XAML, but you aren't referencing it.

```
<Page.DataContext>
<local:Students/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

You would need to reference that object from code if you intend to use it.

```
 private void change_name(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Students)this.DataContext).Name = "MM";
    }
```

Comment: I set the Datacontext in the Mainpage.xaml, ok, will try that.

Comment: @mishael-ogochukwu -- You are setting it in your XAML which creates a new instance of that object and assigns it to DataContext.  Unfortunately that is not the object that you are changing the name on in your event handlers.  See my edit.

Comment: You can verify Brian's answer by putting a breakpoint in the Students constructor, it gets hit twice.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation very similar to the author (if not the same) and only thing I did to fix it is I made my view model a public property. In case of the example above, it would be `Students st;` changed to `public Students st {get; set;}`