# [UWP][C#]Bind ProgressBar value in listview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I'm new in UWP. I want to bind a progress bar value to BackgroundDownloadMAnager.

I have a ListView that shows Active downloads.

```
<ListView Foreground="Black" x:Name="DownloadsList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ListViewItem MinWidth="{Binding MinWidth}">
          <StackPanel Tag="{Binding DownloadGUID}" Orientation="Horizontal">
             <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Image Source="{Binding IMGUri}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                 </StackPanel>
                  <StackPanel MinWidth="{Binding MinWidth}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                    <StackPanel >
                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding APPNAME}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Percentage}"/>
                      </StackPanel>
                      <StackPanel>
                        <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
                      </StackPanel>
                     </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20,0,20,0">
                       <Button Content="&#xE769;" Tag="{Binding DownloadGUID}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Margin="15,0,15,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="PauseBTN_Click" />
                       <Button Content="&#xE711;" Tag="{Binding DownloadGUID}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Margin="0,0,15,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="StopBTN_Click"/>
                     </StackPanel>
                  </StackPanel>
                 </ListViewItem>
               </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
```

C#

```
    public class AppDownload
    {
        public Guid DownloadGUID { get; set; }
        public bool IsResumable { get; set; }
        public BackgroundDownloadProgress Status { get; set; }
        public int DownloadPercent { get; set; }
        public string IMGUri { get; set; }
        public string APPNAME { get; set; }
        public double MinWidth { get; set; }
    }
```

how I get active downloads list

```
    async void ListDownloads()
    {
        var downloads = await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();
        if (downloads.Count >= 1)
            foreach (var item in downloads)
            {
                try
                {
                    var status = item.Progress.Status;
                    var ri = item.GetResponseInformation();
                    var uri = ri.ActualUri.Query;
                    var s1 = uri.Split('=');
                    var s2 = s1[1].Split('&');
                    var appid = s2[0];
                    var appinf = await new JsonData().GetApplicationDetails(Convert.ToInt32(appid));
                    DownloadsList.Items.Add(new AppDownload() { MinWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width - 120 , DownloadGUID = item.Guid, IMGUri = new JsonData().ConvertJSONUriToString(appinf.IconSquare), APPNAME = appinf.NameEnglish + "\t\t\t", DownloadPercent = 100 * Convert.ToInt32(item.Progress.BytesReceived / item.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive) });

                }
                catch { }
            }

    }
```

I want to know how can I dynamically change this progress bar value and also change other things (like one of the TextBlocks text) 
thank you .

Comment: Where is your code going? The first one.

Comment: I can't understand you . what do you mean about where is code going ?

Comment: I mean you code isn't properly indented.

Comment: I update the post and added the function I add the active downloads . 
I didn't code anything for updating values because I don't have any idea about it . This post is all of my code

Comment: Do you get how much amount is downloaded? If not track that value and bind to the progress bar

Comment: by this way the value won't be updated . I made a test listview and made a listviewtemplate for it like this : 
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                        <ProgressBar Name="Prog1" Margin="0,30,0,0" Maximum="{Binding MaxVal}" Value="{Binding Value}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
I add a Dispatcher Timer and update the value of Value in my class but didn't changed in listview .

Comment: I add a breakpoint on my code I see the values binded are changing but the ListViewItem shown on the screen didn't change at all

Comment: It should be ObservableCollection. And your AppDownload class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Comment: return me this error : 
Error CS0535 'NewDownloadsPage.AppDownload' does not implement interface member 'INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged'

Comment: Thats because you are not implementing it. Please refer the code in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376304/inotifypropertychanged-not-working-with-traditonal-binding-but-works-with-compil

Comment: Did it that code work???

Comment: Yes Yes solved . Really thanks man :)